# Displaying the absence of a value (alternative to n/a)

Tags: data-display

An example: rental rates displayed to users in a standard, fixed format. Some rates exist for a time period. Some do not. There could be many rows of data in this format on the page. My opinion is that in this case, lots of n/a symbols, or worse, uppercase N/A symbols look ugly, confuse the expectation of numbers, and are not immediately obvious in their meaning to a typical user.

```
Hour: n/a   Day: $400   Weekend: $9,000
```

I've tried a dash, which I like:

```
Hour: –   Day: $400   Weekend: $9,000
```

There don't seem to be any stylistic recommendations on the web that I can easily find. Are there any other ways to show the absence of a value that all users will understand?

Comment: What is wrong with `n/a`?

Comment: Nothing per se. I'm just looking for semantically equivalent alternatives to n/a that a  typical user will readily understand.

Comment: Not displaying Hour at all or graying it out is another option

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with n/a, then why are you asking for an alternative?  On what basis are we supposed to determine what is "best" when you've given no requirements?

Comment: if the majory of the users does not know what "n/a" means, you must find alternative ways to communicate that concept

Comment: I'd be curious of the context here, if those values are something like budget or spent/earned I'd imagine a $0 would fit quite nicely.

Comment: What makes you believe that your users don't understand a `-` or `n/a`?

Comment: I think they will understand a dash. But if you say to me that each and every single user will know what n/a means, then that is clearly a false statement. Then the question is how many don't know, and the answer is probably more than you think. Will they google what it means? Of course not, and they shouldn't have to. Besides, it can mean not available, not applicable, or no answer, so it's ambiguous anyway. Since no one has come up with an alternative symbol or way to display the absence of a value that I haven't thought of, I think my question has been answered.

Comment: There are lots of non-English speaking people out there. 'n/a' is an abbreviation of English words. If your interface supports other languages you have to find analog in the other language. Or use international symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It largely depends on the context (both visual and user-) around the absence of a value that you're trying to display. If the visual design is as simple as what you've attached, then I'd recommend not going the way of 'microcopy' or 'a fun empty state', and rather, something that's more immediately instructive (like what you have).

'n/a' seems to say, 'not applicable to this instance, don't bother searching for or inputting a value' whereas '-' doesn't communicate that as clearly or speedily. I'd go with the former, and not overthink it.

Comment: It's not just that `-` doesn't communicate "as clearly or speedily".  n/a has a specific meaning that a value does not apply in this case.  `-` doesn't have that specific meaning: it just means there is no data (without communicating a reason).

Comment: +1 for the phrases 'microcopy' and 'empty state'. As it is, without going into detail, I've decided to not display "Hour: –" or "Day: –" etc. at all for certain items depending on context. In a nutshell, I display "Hour: –" or "Day: –"  for items where I don't have a value for those fields but still felt it was important to preserve the structure of the fields for the user. Design is all about context.